# "Should have" usage

Tags: difference

> What do you think Tom **would have** said.
>
> You **should have** breakfast every day.

In the second sentence, is it correct to use **should have**.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think, it's correct.

Comment: **Have** in the first sentence and **have** in the second are quite different in their function. In the second, **have** has a lexical sense: "to have something".

Comment: Indeed, like other types of food intake: *have lunch, have dinner, etc.* The first **have** is used for a clause to complete a conditional sentence.

Answer (score 2):

As CopperKettle points out, **have** is used differently in those two sentences. Here's how we can make those two sentences similar:

**What do you think Tom [would] [have] [said]?

You [should] [have] [eaten] breakfast every day. You have lost weight.**

When there is a past participle (said, eaten), "have" is a helper verb that creates the present perfect.   Alone, with no past participle, it is a verb in its own right (a lexical verb) that means "to own, to possess" or in the case of food "to eat, to consume".

**You should *have breakfast* for energy in the morning.**